# Why can't i draw more than 1 Enemy from my List?

Tags: c#, monogame

My class:

```
public Enemy(Texture2D texture, int delay, int elapsedTime, int frameX, int frameY, float X, float Y, float gravity, float speedX, float speedX2) : base(texture, delay, elapsedTime, frameX, frameY, X, Y, gravity, speedX, speedX2)
{
    this.enemyPos = new Vector2(X,Y);
}

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sp)
    {
        sp.Draw(texture, enemyPos, sourceRect, Color.Red);
    }
```

In my main class I create my list and create 10 enemies:

```
List<Enemy> lista = new List<Enemy>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    enemy = new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("animation"), 500, 0, 0, 0, 100*i, 0, 1, 4f, 4f);
    lista.Add(enemy);
}
```

and then I try to draw them

```
foreach(Enemy enemy in lista)
{
    enemy.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

The result i'm getting is that i only see the last of being drawn. Im quite new to programming so any help would be helpfull.

Comment: I think it's due to `Update()` is being called multiple times per seconds, and creating a `new List<Enemy>()` every time? What happen if you put that as `Field` instead of local variable?

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my problem. The problem was that i wasn't updating all of my enemies... I was only updating one of them 1 I created which explains why I only was being able to see one of the 10 enemies i created. I solved my problem with a foreach loop that goes through all of my enemies in each update.

```
foreach(Enemy e in lista)
{
    e.Update(player);
    e.updateAnimation(gameTime);
    e.Collision(gameTime, map.CollisionTiles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are drawing 10 things, it's just doing it in the same place 10 times. The result looks like a single thing. When you add data, you're going to need to vary it, so you can tell one enemy from another.

Comment: That was my initial assumption, but OP appears to be varying the X coord with `100*i`